# RabbitMQ: client send plain-text and the server view it as base64

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, rabbitmq

I am using Java amqp-client:4.1.0 and RabbitMq server 3.7.6, I used to publish plain text messages to Rabbitmq (the actual payload logical content is XML BTW, some of them are even invalid).

***The problem is:*** In the management portal, when I try to get messages, I can see some are plain-text as expected while other messages are base64 encoded (and NOT all the base64 msgs can be decoded) (WHY!!!).

No other publisher sending to the same, so I am the only publisher.

I am using using below code:

```
Channel myChannel = conn.createChannel();

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap();
props.put("x-max-length-bytes", 90000000l);
myChannel.queueDeclareNoWait("my-queue", false, false, false, props);

myChannel.basicPublish("", "my-queue", new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                        .contentType("text/plain")
                        .contentEncoding("utf-8")
                        .deliveryMode(1)
                        .priority(1)
                        .build()
    , msg.getBytes());
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: So, what is the issue? Just a problem with the management client (a debugging tool)? Is `msg` a string already?

Comment: I edited the description, The issue is that some of the messages are stored as plain string, and others stored as base64, and yes `msg` is string.

Comment: after hours of debugging, I found that those corrupted messages contains arabic characters, that was not correctly encoded, I've duplicated this, by sending the same message without the arabic chars, message was persisted correctly. Don't know why rabbitMQ doing this, do you have any idea why?

Comment: I would suspect the binary formatter in use, but there's really no telling. If there are invalid ASCII characters, then the formatter should raise an exception. The management plug in is a maintenance and debugging tool, and suspected issues with it could be reported via their bug tracker.

Comment: Yes, this is what I will be going to do, once I am back from my vacation, it is definitely a bug! Thanks @theMayer